# iDeal not listed in omnipay-rabobank library - [Laravel Framework]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, omnipay

I'm currently using the **Omnipay** extension library to simply handle my Rabobank omnikassa transactions. Now when i use the code below i get a selection of all credit card methods but **IDEAL** and **MINITIX** are not listed on the page. Not sure what i'm doing wrong, first time i'm using an external library to handle my payments. Rabobank Omnikassa should display all available payment methods on default.

**The Library:**
https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-rabobank

**My Code: iDealController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;


class iDealController extends Controller
{
   public function loadPage()
   {
       $sOrderId = 'WEB' . time(); // This should be unique - Order id
       $sTransactionReference = $sOrderId . date('His'); // This should be unique - Identifier of transaction
       $amount = 10.00;

       $gateway = Omnipay::create('Rabobank');


       $request = $gateway->purchase(array(
           'testMode' => true,
           'merchantId' => '002020000000001',
           'keyVersion' => '1',
           'secretKey' => '002020000000001_KEY1',
           'amount' => $amount,
           'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:8888/',
           'automaticResponseUrl' => 'http://localhost:8888/',
           'currency' => 'EUR',
           'transactionReference' => $sTransactionReference,
           'orderId' => $sOrderId,
           'customerLanguage' => "EN"
           )
       );

       $data = $request->getData();
       $response = $request->sendData($data);

       if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
           // payment was successful: update database
           print_r($response);
       } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
           // redirect to offsite payment gateway
           $response->redirect();
       } else {
           // payment failed: display message to customer
           echo $response->getMessage();
       }

       return view('omnikassa');
   }
}
```

When i add: `'PaymentMethod' => 'IDEAL'` to the `request` array it gives the following error: `Technical problem  : code=03 message=None of the merchant's payment means is compliant with the transaction context`. So definitely something is going wrong.

Comment: Seems like a Rabobank related issue as this is already the case in the standard php files which can be found here: https://www.rabobank.nl/bedrijven/betalen/geld-ontvangen/rabo-omnikassa/support/. I've contacted their helpdesk. Information regarding this topic i will post here if there will be any.

Comment: There is a malfunction in the test environment of the rabobank. Which causes the above problem. The code is fine for the rest.